# Golang text/Templates and the use of {{with }} {{end}}

Tags: templates, go, go-templates

The question is this that the first example program listed in `text/template`
builds a form letter.

While the letter is parsed with a Range, why does `.Gift` need to be used via the

```
{{with .Gift}} ..... {{.}}  {{end}}
```

`.Name` and `.Attended` were directly addressed. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Because the `Gift` is optional, and if no `Gift` is provided, we don't want to thank for anything in the letter; but if `Gift` is provided, we want to say thanks for the gift.

The `{{with}}` action executes its body conditionally, only if the passed pipeline is not empty:

```
{{with pipeline}} T1 {{end}}
    If the value of the pipeline is empty, no output is generated;
    otherwise, dot is set to the value of the pipeline and T1 is
    executed.
```

So the example contains this:

```
{{with .Gift -}}
Thank you for the lovely {{.}}.
{{end}}
```

This means that if `.Gift` is not empty, then include the "thank you" sentence in the output (letter). If `.Gift` is empty, the "thank you" will be omitted.